# Android - Button Timer (Handler - RemoveCallback won't stop PostDelayed)

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I'm currently working on an android app for adjusting seats. One feature I want to include is to make the seat move faster, when the button to move the seat in one direction is touched for a certain time.

For that purpose, I want to start like this: When I touch a button (in my code "seat_down") the app should send the signal "1". After a certain time (in my code it's five seconds) touching the button (and only when it's still touched after these five seconds) the app should send the signal "0". Thus, if I'm touching the button for only four seconds and then let go, the app should only have sent the signal "1", and not a "0" afterwards.

You can see the code at the bottom.

What is my app really doing?

Touching the button for longer than five seconds, the app works as I want it to. So it's sending in the moment of touching the button the signal "1" and after five seconds the "0". Nice!

When I'm touching the button for a shorter moment than five seconds, it also sends the "1" in the beginning and after five seconds the "0".  :((

Somehow, "myHandler.removeCallbacks(MyRunnable)" is not working when I'm not touching the button anymore. But the app sends the message "2" when I let the button go, thus it is recognizing "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP". 
When I'm writing the "myHandler.removeCallbacks(MyRunnable)" in another position of my code, for example a line before the "return true", it stops the postDelayed perfectly. Unfortunately, it stops the  postDelayed all the time, even if I'm still touching the button.

I also tried to do a timer with the standard loops of java and searched a lot in the internet, but I couldn't find something that really solves my problem. I know that there is the "OnLongClickListener", but the time span until it's activated is too short. I also read about the Timer method and the AsyncTask, but I was hoping to handle it without that.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this! Thank you!!!

CODE

```
   seat_down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
   seat_down.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           Handler myHandler = new Handler();

           final Runnable MyRunnable = new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {


                   String message2 = "0";
                   sendMessage(message2); 


               }
           };



           switch(event.getAction()) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


           String message1 = "1";
           sendMessage(message1);


           myHandler.postDelayed(MyRunnable, 5000);


       break;

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

           myHandler.removeCallbacks(MyRunnable);
           break;

       }
return true;

       }} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a handler everytime you call onTouch... the handler you send your runnable to and the handler you call removeCallbacks on are two different handlers, same with your runnable.
Just create the handler and the runnable in your onCreate... or with

```
if(handler==null) handler = new Handler() ...
```

Update :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendMessage("0");
        }
    };


    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                sendMessage("1");
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    Log.i("Message", message);
}
```

Comment: I copied my Handler und Runnable from the onResume to the onCreate.
There it says that myHandler and MyRunnable are not used. In my onResume seat_down method it says, that myHandler cannot be resolved and MyRunnable cannot be resolved to a variable. 

Your second suggestion I did not really understand. I tried to include it in the onCreate (“dead code”) and also in the onResume seat_down-method (“myHandler cannot be resolved to a variable”).

Comment: @user3256557, check my update. You have to create your Handler and Runnable outside of your OnTouchListener.